How to make this node configuration only convert the outer shell into blocks, instead of filling it fully
Im using this node setup to convert ships from eve online into a blocky blueprint for minecraft
files are .stl that only have the outer shell, somehow my geometry nodes modifier fills it fully, reducing performance greatly, i only need the outer layer to be represented as blocks


It seems this is a duplicate: GeoNodes : How to delete interiors faces after voxelisation?

not working sadly, its leaving a lot of emptied faces


Add a Mesh to Points node, connect Input Geometry to Mesh
Delete the Distribute Points in Volume node
Connect Points from Mesh to Points and Points from Instance on Points


didnt work, a bunch of overlapping blocks on top of each other

alright sorry. have you looked at the comment on your original question, it looks like the solution worked

not really, its leaving a lot of faces deleted on the outside
